# Multiple job applications

Tags: job-search, applications

I recently submitted multiple applications to 1 company (but for different teams). The jobs were for data science (DS)/data analyst (DA) positions:

1. DS1
2. DA1
3. DA2

I have a couple of (related) questions about this situation:

1. My submission for DA2 was accidental. The company uses a single profile that is sent with each application, so as soon as you hit the "apply" button on a job, it just gets submitted. I logged into the web portal but couldn't find a way to delete or withdraw my application. I have just been contacted (via email) about this job, but I'm not particularly interested given the submission was accidental. What's the best way to communicate this? This is complicated by my next point...
2. After some consideration, I've decided that I'm not particularly interested in *any* DA job. How do I communicate this, in conjunction with the point above, while still leaving the door open for the DS1 position at the company?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just reply to the email you got about the DA2 position saying something like this:

> Could I interview for the Data Specialist 1 position instead? That's the
> position I had intended to apply for - applying for the Data Analyst
> position was an accident.
>
> Thanks!

As for the DA1 position...  well, the fact that the above email I typed up didn't specify *which* Data Analyst position might help. But if it doesn't I wouldn't worry about it.

If they contact you about the DA1 position *before* they've responded to your DA2 response you could send the same response as above. And if they contact you *after* responding to your DA2 email you could respond with this:

> I'm already in talks with your company about the Data Specialist 1
> position so I would like to withdraw my consideration for the Data
> Analyst position whilst still remaining in the running for the
> Data Specialist position.
>
> Thanks!

Comment: So in my case I'd like to eliminate consideration for both DA positions (DA1 and DA2), and would only like to pursue DS1 (if they contact me). Do I tell the hiring manager for DA2 that DA2 was an accident and to withdraw both my DA applications? Or only mention the part about the accident?

Comment: @SearchingForJobs - I've updated my answer!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably proceed with DA2 to the first phone screen. That at least gets you a foot in the door and a real person to talk to.

There is no harm in checking this out in more detail and you will most likely learn something about the company and the position. If you confirm in the phone screen that the DA position isn't what you want, you can bring up the DS1.

This you will need to play by ear: If you are lucky, it's the same recruiter or they at least know the department and the other recruiter. Could also be that's in a different part of the company that the recruiter is no interest in dealing with. In any case, there is no harm in asking.

It's also perfectly okay to say "thanks for sharing all the details, that's been very helpful. However, I don't think that's great fit me at this point". That's what phone screens are for and most recruiters will appreciate a quick and clear answer, so they can move on.